# Integration Services run package in synchronously fails due to time out

Tags: ssis, timeout

I'm trying to execute a SSIS package from a store procedure using the create execution command but i need to know when the package finished its job so y use the SYNCHRONIZED parameter, the problem is that running ot as SYNCHRONIZED it fails with timeout and status "Unexpected Termination" after 30 seconds, but when I run UNSYNCHRONIZED everything works well, please your help.

This is my procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_upload] 
as
begin
declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
    @folder_name=N'Folder',
    @project_name=N'Project',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
    @reference_id=Null

DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,
      @object_type=50,
      @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
      @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  
      @object_type=50, 
      @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', 
      @parameter_value=1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
Select @execution_id
end
```

When I run it with the parameter N'SYNCHRONIZED value = 0 it runs ok, but if i change it to 1 it fails with timeout after 30 seconds.

I need it to be synchronous because I need to know when the package finishes its job before reporting the execution id.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the package execution at fault here, it's your usage.

Assume package takes 45 seconds to run. You have Synchronized set to true in your procedure and run it from SSMS. 45 seconds later, it's complete.

Same setup, but now you run it from your .net app. 30 seconds in, boom, timeout bad things happen. What's happening is the [default command timeout of 30 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbcommand.commandtimeout?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_IDbCommand_CommandTimeout) is hitting you.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
// Change execution timeout to 50 seconds to ensure our 45 second process runs
command.CommandTimeout = 50;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Text = "EXECUTE dbo.sp_upload";
```